# Sum fields by invoicenumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I need to do an update of fields in a table - but only if the sum of a field differs from the sum of fields in another table.

Something along these lines:

```
if sum (KundFaktura.FakturaBeloppUtl) <>  SUM (KundFakturaHandelser.BeloppUtl) **then update**
```

The summation need these conditions:

```
KundFakturaHandelser.FakturaNr
KundFaktura.FakturaNr
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I don't even know where to start :(

Comment: This you can implement by using simple sql join query. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Join doesnt do a summation ?

Comment: SELECT
    fakturanr,
    SUM(BeloppUtl) Sumhandelser
FROM
    KundFakturaHandelser
WHERE 
    Datum > '2018-01-30' and Serie <> 'b'
GROUP BY
    fakturanr;


SELECT
    fakturanr,
    SUM(FakturaBeloppUtl) Sumfaktura
FROM
    KundFaktura
WHERE 
    FakturaDatum > '2018-01-30'
GROUP BY
    fakturanr;




Update KundFakturaHandelser set KundFakturaHandelser.BeloppUtl =KundFaktura.FakturaBeloppUtl
from kundfaktura,KundFakturaHandelser
where KundFaktura.ForfalloDatum >'2019-01-01' and KundFakturaHandelser.FakturaNr=KundFaktura.FakturaNr

Comment: how do is use my "select codes" as conditions?